# Minando texto con python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, xml

Hola estoy tratando de obtener un xml en python, tengo el siguente texto plano:

```
CAPITULO I
Del Contenido de esta Ley
ARTICULO 1. 
Esta Ley regula:
a) la elección e los Delegados a las Asambleas Municipales y Provinciales y de los Diputados a la Asamblea Nacional del Poder Popular;
b) la constitución de las Asambleas Municipales y Provinciales del Poder Popular y la elección por las de sus Presidentes   y Vicepresidentes;
c) la constitución de la Asamblea Nacional del Poder Popular y la elección por la de su Presidente, Vicepresidente y  Secretario, así como del Presidente, Primer Vicepresidente, Vicepresidentes, Secretario y dem?miembros del Consejo de Estado;
ch) la forma de cubrir los cargos electivos vacantes;
d) la votación los referendos convocados por la Asamblea Nacional del Poder Popular.
CAPITULO II
Del Proceso Electoral
ARTICULO 2. 
Los procesos electorales que establece esta Ley son:
a)  elecciones generales, en las que se elige a los Diputados a la Asamblea Nacional del Poder Popular, su Presidente, Vicepresidente y Secretario, al  Presidente, Primer Vicepresidente, Vicepresidentes, Secretario y dem? miembros del Consejo de Estado, a los Delegados a las Asambleas Provinciales y Municipales del Poder Popular y a sus Presidentes y Vicepresidentes;
b) elecciones parciales, en las que se elige a los Delegados a las Asambleas Municipales del Poder Popular y sus Presidentes y Vicepresidentes.
```

Ahora tengo el siguente codigo python:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

ley = ET.Element("ley")
cont_articulos = 0
cont_capitulos = 0

archivo = open('D:\ley.txt', 'r')
linea = archivo.readline()

while linea != '':

    primer_palabra = linea.split(' ', 1)
    if primer_palabra[0] == 'CAPITULO' or primer_palabra[0] == 'capitulo' or primer_palabra[0] == 'Capitulo':
        titulo = archivo.readline()
        capitulo = ET.SubElement(ley, "capitulo", id="3", titulo=titulo)

        linea = archivo.readline()
        primer_palabra = linea.split(' ', 1)
        if primer_palabra[0] == 'ARTICULO' or primer_palabra[0] == 'articulo' or primer_palabra[0] == 'Articulo':
            cont_articulos = cont_articulos + 1
            articulo = ET.SubElement(capitulo, "articulo", id="1")

            linea = archivo.readline()
            primer_palabra = linea.split(' ', 1)
            while primer_palabra[0] != 'CAPITULO':
                texto = ET.SubElement(articulo, "texto").text = linea
                linea = archivo.readline()
                primer_palabra = linea.split(' ', 1)

    linea = archivo.readline()

archivo.close()
arbol = ET.ElementTree(ley)
arbol.write("D:\prueba.xml")
```

y el resultado que me da es el siguente:

```
<ley>
<capitulo id="3" titulo="Del Contenido de esta Ley&#10;">
    <articulo id="1">
        <texto>Esta Ley regula:
        </texto>
        <texto>a) la elecci&#243;n e los Delegados a las Asambleas Municipales y Provinciales y de los Diputados a
            la Asamblea Nacional del Poder Popular;
        </texto>
        <texto>b) la constituci&#243;n de las Asambleas Municipales y Provinciales del Poder Popular y la elecci&#243;n
            por las de sus Presidentes y Vicepresidentes;
        </texto>
        <texto>c) la constituci&#243;n de la Asamblea Nacional del Poder Popular y la elecci&#243;n por la de su
            Presidente, Vicepresidente y Secretario, as&#237; como del Presidente, Primer Vicepresidente,
            Vicepresidentes, Secretario y dem?miembros del Consejo de Estado;
        </texto>
        <texto>ch) la forma de cubrir los cargos electivos vacantes;
        </texto>
        <texto>d) la votaci&#243;n los referendos convocados por la Asamblea Nacional del Poder Popular.
        </texto>
    </articulo>
</capitulo>
```

como ven solo logro añadir al xml el primer capitulo y el su articulo, no se por que no me añade el capitulo 2, alguna idea. Tambien me gustaria saber como transformarlo a json.

Comment: Parece que el código no está correctamente indentado. La primera línea tras el `while linea!='':` debería estar indentada, y a partir de ahí es difícil saber dónde acaba el cuerpo del while. Posiblemente un error al pegar el código. Por favor corrígelo para poder eliminar fuentes de confusión.

Comment: si creo que al copiarlo se modifico la identacion, ya lo solucione.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código tiene varios problemas. Corregiré el más importante que motivó tu pregunta, y te comentaré después otras posibles mejoras.

### Corregir el error básico y mejoras menores

La razón por la que no detectabas correctamente el siguiente capítulo es que, mientras estás recorriendo el texto del artículo en el  segundo `while`, estás mirando como condición de salida que la línea leída comience por `CAPITULO`.

Cuando alcanzas esa condición, ya has leído esa línea. Por tanto cuando al salir del bucle interno haces otro `archivo.readline()`, estás leyendo la línea siguiente al encabezado "CAPITULO" y por tanto ya te has saltado ese encabezado y no detectas el siguiente capítulo.

La solución es hacer ese `linea = archivo.readline()` que haces al final del bucle principal en un `else`, como muestro más abajo.

Otro error grave es el bucle `while` interno, cuya única condición de parada es detectar si se alcanzó otro "CAPITULO" ¿qué ocurre si se llega al final del fichero sin que aparezca otro capítulo? Se quedaría atrapado en un bucle infinito. El problema se corrige haciendo que el bucle se repita mientras no se encuentre "capítulo" *y además* no leamos una línea vacía.

Aprovecho para hacer algunas mejoras para reducir el tamaño del código, tales como usar `linea.startswith()` para detectar si la línea comienza por una cierta palabra (sin necesidad de romperla con `split()` y acceder después a sus trozos), o de `linea.lower()` para pasarla a minúsculas y así no tener que comparar con diferentes capitalizaciondes de los encabezados.

Este es el código con las correcciones mencionadas:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

ley = ET.Element("ley")
cont_articulos = 0
cont_capitulos = 0

archivo = open('D:\ley.txt', 'r')

linea = archivo.readline()
while linea != '':
  if linea.lower().startswith('capitulo'):
    titulo = archivo.readline()
    capitulo = ET.SubElement(ley, "capitulo", id="3", titulo=titulo)

    linea = archivo.readline()
    if linea.lower().startswith('articulo'):
      cont_articulos = cont_articulos + 1
      articulo = ET.SubElement(capitulo, "articulo", id="1")
      linea = archivo.readline()
      while linea!="" and not linea.lower().startswith("capitulo"):
        texto = ET.SubElement(articulo, "texto").text = linea
        linea = archivo.readline()
  else:
    linea = archivo.readline()


archivo.close()
arbol = ET.ElementTree(ley)
arbol.write("D:\prueba.xml")
```

### Posibles fuentes de problemas

Tal como está tu código no detecta correctamente si hay varios "artículos" dentro de un mismo "capítulo".

En el XML que generas, todos los capítulos tienen un mismo `id="3"` y todos los artículos un mismo `id="1"`. Esto no es correcto ya que se entiende que los `id` han de ser únicos (no ya los de cada artículo o capítulo, sino los de cada elemento XML, al menos ese es el convenio).

### Conversión a JSON

De forma general no es posible convertir XML en JSON sin tomar ciertas decisiones. El XML permite tener atributos (y de hecho tu XML los tiene, tales como `id`, `titulo`) mientras que JSON no permite tal cosa y debes decidir cómo almacenar esa información en forma de diccionario.

Otra cosa a decidir es qué hacer con los retornos de carro y espacios en blanco que hay entre los diferentes tags. ¿Deben ser ignorados? Un parser XML que lea tu salida con la misión de convertirlo a JSON no lo ignoraría por defecto.

Un convenio habitual suele ser:

- Si el elemento no tiene atributos, usar como clave de diccionario el nombre del elemento, y como valor su contenido (texto)
- Si el elemento tiene atributos, entonces la clave seguirá siendo el nombre del elemento, pero su valor será otro diccionario en el que cada atributo es una clave de nombre `"@atributo"` (que lleva asociado como valor el valor del atributo), más una clave adicional llamada por ejemplo `"#text"` y cuyo valor es el contenido del elemento.

Así, por ejemplo, tu XML:

```xml
<ley>
<capitulo id="3" titulo="Del Contenido de esta Ley">
    <articulo id="1">
        <texto>Esta Ley regula:</texto>
        <texto>a) bla bla</texto>
        <texto>b) más bla bla</texto>
    </articulo>
</capitulo>
</ley>
```

Podría dar lugar a este json:

```
{
  "ley": {
    "capitulo": {
       "@id": "3",
       "titulo": "Del Contenido de esta Ley".
       "articulo": {
          "@id": "1",
          "texto": [
            { "#text": "Esta ley regula:" },
            { "#text": "a) bla bla" },
            { "#text": "b) mas bla bla" }
          ]
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Pero también a este (según cómo decidas tratar los elementos `<texto>` repetidos):

```
{
   "ley" : {
      "capitulo" : {
         "@id" : "3",
         "@titulo" : "Del Contenido de esta Ley",
         "articulo" : {
            "@id" : "1",
            "texto" : [
               "Esta Ley regula:",
               "a) bla bla",
               "b) mas bla bla"
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Mientras no especifiques más claramente cómo quieres el JSON, la tarea no es posible. En todo caso, échale un vistazo a  [xml2json](https://github.com/hay/xml2json) que admite varias opciones.

## Actualización

Por petición del usuario, muestro a continuación cómo podría evitarse el uso del XML intermedio, por el mecanismo de construir estructuras de datos nativas python para ir almacenando la información antes de volcarla como JSON.

No obstante, sigue sin estar especificado qué formato concreto ha de tener el JSON, si es posible la existencia de varios artículos dentro de cada capítulo, qué "claves" se han de almacenar y cómo se llaman, etc. por lo que he tomado las siguientes decisiones:

1. El objeto principal tendrá una sola clave llamada `"ley"`, y su valor será una lista de objetos.
2. Cada uno de esos objetos representa un capítulo, y tiene las siguientes claves:

   - `"capitulo"`, cuyo valor es el número del capítulo extraído del texto, tomando la última palabra del encabezado
   - `"titulo"`, cuyo valor es el texto del capítulo tomado de la línea siguiente al encabezado
   - `"id"` cuyo valor es `"3"` (parece ser un requisito del problema)
   - `"articulos"`, cuyo valor es una lista de objetos que se definen en el punto 3
3. Cada objeto de la lista de articulos representa un artículo y contiene las siguientes claves:

   - `"articulo"`, cuyo valor es el número del artículo tomado de la última palabra en la cabecera del artículo.
   - `"id"`, cuyo valor es `"1"` (parece ser otro requisito del problema)
   - `"texto"`, cuyo valor es una lista de cadenas, siendo cada cadena una línea tal como ha sido leída del fichero para el cuerpo de ese artículo.

En definitiva, una vez parseado el ejemplo de texto suministrado, la estructura resultante sería (indentado para mayor claridad):

```
{
 "ley": [
  {
   "capitulo": "I",
   "titulo": "Del Contenido de esta Ley\n",
   "id": "3",
   "articulos": [
    {
     "articulo": "1.",
     "id": "1",
     "texto": [
      "Esta Ley regula:\n",
      "a) la elecci\u00f3n e los Delegados a las Asambleas Municipales y Provinciales y de los Diputados a la Asamblea Nacional del Poder Popular;\n",
      "b) la constituci\u00f3n de las Asambleas Municipales y Provinciales del Poder Popular y la elecci\u00f3n por las de sus Presidentes   y Vicepresidentes;\n",
      "c) la constituci\u00f3n de la Asamblea Nacional del Poder Popular y la elecci\u00f3n por la de su Presidente, Vicepresidente y  Secretario, as\u00ed como del Presidente, Primer Vicepresidente, Vicepresidentes, Secretario y dem?miembros del Consejo de Estado;\n",
      "ch) la forma de cubrir los cargos electivos vacantes;\n",
      "d) la votaci\u00f3n los referendos convocados por la Asamblea Nacional del Poder Popular.\n"
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "capitulo": "II",
   "titulo": "Del Proceso Electoral\n",
   "id": "3",
   "articulos": [
    {
     "articulo": "2.",
     "id": "1",
     "texto": [
      "Los procesos electorales que establece esta Ley son:\n",
      "a)  elecciones generales, en las que se elige a los Diputados a la Asamblea Nacional del Poder Popular, su Presidente, Vicepresidente y Secretario, al  Presidente, Primer Vicepresidente, Vicepresidentes, Secretario y dem? miembros del Consejo de Estado, a los Delegados a las Asambleas Provinciales y Municipales del Poder Popular y a sus Presidentes y Vicepresidentes;\n",
      "b) elecciones parciales, en las que se elige a los Delegados a las Asambleas Municipales del Poder Popular y sus Presidentes y Vicepresidentes."
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Lo mostrado aquí podría ser tanto una variable python como su representación JSON ya que en este caso coinciden al ser todas las claves y valores de tipo string.

El código que almacena en la variable `ley` un diccionario como el que acabo de mostrar más arriba sería:

```
ley = {"ley": []}  # Una lista de capitulos
cont_articulos = 0
cont_capitulos = 0

archivo = open('ley.txt', 'r')

linea = archivo.readline()
while linea != '':
  if linea.lower().startswith('capitulo'):
    cap_num = linea.split()[-1]
    titulo = archivo.readline()
    # Crear capítulo nuevo
    capitulo = {"capitulo": cap_num, 
                "titulo": titulo, 
                "id": "3", 
                "articulos": []}
    # Añadirlo a la ley
    ley["ley"].append(capitulo)

    linea = archivo.readline()
    if linea.lower().startswith('articulo'):
      art_num = linea.split()[-1]
      cont_articulos = cont_articulos + 1
      # Crear articulo nuevo
      articulo = {"articulo": art_num, 
                  "id": "1", 
                  "texto": []} 
      # Añadirlo al capítulo
      capitulo["articulos"].append(articulo)
      linea = archivo.readline()
      while linea!="" and not linea.lower().startswith("capitulo"):
        # Añadir la línea al texto del artículo
        articulo["texto"].append(linea)
        linea = archivo.readline()
  else:
    linea = archivo.readline()

archivo.close()
```

Este diccionario puede volcarse a JSON de forma trivial:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(ley, indent=True))
```

Y produciría la salida mostrada anteriormente. Poner `indent=False` si se quiere quitar la indentación para que ocupe menos. Poner `indent=None` (u omitirlo, pues es el valor por defecto) para obtener la representación más compacta en la que todo está en una sola línea

### Advertencia

Aunque la estructura de datos aquí mostrada prevé el caso de que haya varios artículos dentro de cada capítulo, el código que lee el fichero en cambio es básicamente el mismo suministrado por el usuario en la pregunta, el cual no tiene en cuenta esta posibilidad.

Tratar correctamente ese caso complicaría el código, pues es necesario detectar si, mientras se está en el bucle `while()` interno que va acumulando el texto del artículo, aparece de nuevo una cabecera "ARTICULO", en cuyo caso habria que crear un diccionario nuevo para ese artículo.

Tampoco funcionaría correctamente si, entre la cabecera CAPITULO y la cabecera ARTICULO hubiera más de una línea.

En general, tratar correctamente una entrada de texto desestructurada y compleja requeriría la creación de un parser más sofisticado, usando quizás herramientas como `pyparsing`.

Comment: gracias man me sirvio de mucho, de todos modos tengo ue estudiarme bien eso de convertirlo a json porque ese es el objetivo

Comment: y lo de los id lo que pasa es que el json final debe tener en vez de articulo o capitulo, "categoria": "Articulo 1" o "categoria": "Capitulo 1" es por eso que los id son fijo, los articulos con 1, los capitulos con 3, las secciones que ahi no aparecen con id 2 etc

Comment: @FelixAMarreroPentón Si el objetivo final es el json, no veo por qué primero has de pasar por XML. Todo sería más sencillo si fueras guardando los datos en estructuras nativas python (diccionarios, listas) pues esas se convierten directamente en JSON sin problemas. Respecto a lo de `id`, mejor elegir otro nombre para el atributo ya que, insisto, un atributo llamado `id` se usa normalmente para identificar de forma _única_ a un elemento del XML, y en tu caso no sería único (habría varios elementos con id 3, por ejemplo)

Comment: podrias ponerme un  ejemplo de poner el texto en un diccionario

Comment: @FelixAMarreroPentón Lee la actualización y también la advertencia final. Mira a ver también si las decisiones que he tomado sobre la estructura del JSON son apropiadas.

Comment: sos un cark tio, con diccionario es por mucha mas facil, solo no quiero que no me aparesca el "\n" al final de cada linea, no lo necesito

Comment: @FelixAMarreroPentón Pues añade un `.rstrip()` tras cada `readline()`. Eso elimina los espacios que pueda haber al final de la línea y el retorno de carro. Si también quieres quitar los espacios iniciales que pudiera haber, usa `.strip()`

Comment: to funciona ok, pero por ahora solo trabajo con capitulo y articulo, pero cuando comience a añadir libros, titulos y secciones voy atener mucho codigo repetido por lo que estoy tratando de evitar eso y estoy poniendo el codigo en una funcion aparte del articulo pero no funciona

Comment: @FelixAMarreroPentón Para un caso así te vale más investigar en el uso de un parser "de verdad", en lugar de tratar de hacer el tuyo "a mano". Yo plantearía una pregunta aparte, del estilo de "¿Qué técnica puedo usar para parsear texto semi-estructurado?" Y poner un ejemplo del tipo de texto que debes analizar, junto con tus intentos de hacerlo "manualmente" y de cómo se complica a medida que quieres tener en cuenta más "apartados".